# getimagesize() error: "failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

Tags: php, getimagesize

I get the following error:

> getimagesize(barbie2.jpeg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or      directory

On line:

```
list($hight, $width) = getimagesize($name);
```

Comment: is this an uploaded file? is the file "barbie2.jpeg" is in the same directly as your php file?

Comment: Related: [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456)

Answer (score 8):

in getimagesize() you need to specify path of the image. Probably it is not getting image path so it is giving you error.

your file from where you have called this function and image location is different so it is giving you error.

Comment: Thats sounds great. I just used this function to find height and width of an uploaded image. Tried with file name only. That is what happened.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the path of the image by using `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]` because when you upload the file is stored in the temp directory.